# Audio- The use of trrs cable

Tags: audio

I didn't do any research until after lol. I bought a trrs to trrs cable. Will I be okay to use this for my H5 recorder to my Sony a6400 camera? Or will I need a trs to trrs ?

Comment: Plugs are only the first of your issues. Impedance-matching comes a close second. See https://www.cablechick.com.au/blog/understanding-trrs-and-audio-jacks/ for the first. Ask a new question if that's not sufficient. You didn't actually explain what you are trying to achieve. Are you trying to sync your audio to video as you shoot it? If so, that's what the clapper is for. Such as DaVinci will quite happily align your audio to video at import, using the camera's cheap mic against your 'real' audio.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](https://helpguide.sony.net/ilc/1810/v1/en/contents/TP0002280326.html) page, the Sony a6400 has a 3.5" stereo mini jack microphone input.

And the Zoom has a 3.5" stereo line out mini jack [p144 of the PDF](https://zoomcorp.com/media/documents/E_H5_v2.pdf).

Both devices look to me like they probably use TRS not TRRS, although it's not clear from the manuals.

It might work correctly, assuming both devices are wired the same way (e.g. my TRRS apple earbud & mic work correctly in a TRS wired headphone socket).

(This is also assuming the Sony can handle line level inputs which are usually higher than mic input levels).